# Alternative phrase to “out of the corner of eye”

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

I am looking for a phrase similar to a “out of corner of my eye”. I came across this phrase in a Hollywood movie, and was wondering if I can use an alternative phrase to this?

Here is the context, I am trying to use the phrase in,

> I recently took a resolution to avoid all sports news. That’s why I was being very careful, when I was turning the pages of newspaper. As I turned to sports page, out of the corner of my eye, I noticed the word Yankees. I immediately looked away, and turned to next page.

Can somebody recommend an alternative word/expression to this?

Comment: Your piece is missing some articles - I recently took a resolution to avoid all sports news. That’s why I was being very careful, when I was turning the pages of **a** newspaper. As I turned to **the** sports page, out of the corner of my eye, I noticed the word Yankees. I immediately looked away, and turned to **the** next page.

Answer (score 2):

"In my peripheral vision" or "at the edge of my vision" would express the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could say "with a side glance"

Comment: A sidelong glance is deliberate; this was accidental.